# exoplayer issues with aac+ stream API 19 KitKat and lower

Tags: android, exoplayer

Hi i already created my app with exoplayer version r1.5.3 in android studio when i try API 23 or 20 the app plays the stream without issues, but if i go to API 19 i get this error:

```
01-30 12:01:36.063 3996-4269/com.streaming507.aacplayer E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal track renderer error.
com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://streaming507.com:9986
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.maybeThrowError(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:154)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.maybeThrowError(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:145)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.incrementalPrepareInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:283)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:205)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
                                                                                  Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://streaming507.com:9986
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:202)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.DefaultUriDataSource.open(DefaultUriDataSource.java:135)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorSampleSource.java:741)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:209)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: ICY 200 OK
                                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.setStatusLine(RawHeaders.java:108)
                                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
                                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
                                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
                                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
                                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
                                                                                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:199)
```

im using this to play:

```
 Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
                String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, "ExoPlayerDemo");
                DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, null, userAgent);
                ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
                        uri, dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE * BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT);
                audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);
                exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);

                return true;
```

How i can fix this to play aac+ streams on API 19 and lower?

thank you

Comment: Did you get a solution? Please help me get getDuration() for ExoPlayer and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777975/not-able-to-get-getduration-for-aac-file-using-exoplayer